# Copy Data From One Database To Another In Same Table

Tags: mysql

I want to copy data from one database which has table named domains to another database which also has the table named domains to it.

I have tried doing it using phpmyadmin but it doesn't copy maybe because of Auto_increment values. it just doesn't get copied to another database.table.

I want to know what can be done in this regard? also I don't want to copy old ID(auto_increment) values from first database to another.

phpmyadmin response.

```
 #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

both the structures are same in the databases still this.

My Query.

```
 INSERT INTO `site1`.`domains`
 SELECT * FROM `site33`.`domains`
```

^ This much is fixed.
now comes the auto_increment problem I Get:

```
  #1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Comment: PHPMyAdmin must have given you some feedback. Maybe it's better to read that message instead of letting people guess.

Comment: #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: What query are you using..? Can you paste your query in your question..?

Comment: Now I am getting duplicate entry problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an insert statement that has an incorrect number of values, for instance:

for a table with columns `a`, `b` and `c`, these are all invalid:

```
INSERT INTO YourTable VALUES (1, 2);

INSERT INTO YourTable(b, c) VALUES (1, 2, 3);

INSERT INTO YourTable(a, b, c) VALUES (2, 3);
```

The number of columns in the column list must match the number of values in the value list.

You may only omit the column list, but only if you specify one value for each column and in the order in which the columns exist in the table. This is bad practice, though. It is better to always specify the exact columns you need.

Comment: That's probably because you're inserting values that already exist. It could also be that you got a unique index on a field that you do not explicitly copy. You target database will fill in NULL or a default value in that case, and will fail if the column is set to be unique

Comment: yes, that is the problem. I would rather not copy the auto_incremented value to another database.

Answer (score 9):

You could do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO database2.table1 (field2,field3)
SELECT table2.field2,table2.field3
FROM table2;
```

**Note:**
Do not include the column which is auto increment in your insert and select statement.

[Sql Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d6768/1)